# Data is merging into one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I converted a utf-16 file to utf-8 with notepad++.

After importing it to python I noticed that all my columns are merging into one, like this:

Before importing it

```
   0      1      2
0 Time  Voltage Temp.
1   5     10     25
2   6     13     26
3   7     17     30
```

After importing it

```
          0
0 Time Voltage Temp.
1   5     10     25
2   6     13     26
3   7     17     30
```

I am using pandas to read the file as follows: `df = pd.read_csv('Values.csv')`

How can I make them stay on the way they were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file uses tabs or spaces as separators, try using

`df = pd.read_csv("Values.csv", sep="\t")`

or

`df = pd.read_csv("Values.csv", sep=None)`